# Incomplete stack blitz ngbd table example

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Has anyone worked with the "complete example" on ngbd table.
[example list](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples)
I am trying to set up the complete example found at the bottom.
When loading the stack-blitz it gets an import error.
"Import error, can't find files:
./country.service
./sortable.directive"

Does anyone have a example combining the sorting,paginating and search/filtering with ng-bootstrap?

Currently I am trying to combine the standalone examples into one without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a working demo. I found the missing classes [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/table/demos/complete), so copied them across into [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bcreq?file=app%2Ftable-complete.ts).